# Conexão banco de dados no Unity

Tags: banco-de-dados, unity-5

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo no unity e chegamos na parte em que é necessário armazenar a pontuação dos jogadores em um banco de dados. Essas informações serão utilizadas no rank que aparecerá ao final da rodada. No entanto, não entendo como fazer essa parte. Alguém possui alguma dica? Obrigada.

Answer (score 3):

A Unity não tem suporte a banco de dados, no lugar você pode usar um arquivo XML ou JSON se forem poucos dados. Se forem muitos, melhor utilizar algum serviço pela internet.

Pra ajudar: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer

Comment: Quando você diz um serviço na internet, você fala sobre o que exatamente?

Comment: Tem várias opções, vcs podem criar um serviço em nuvem simples de vcs (mas aí vai ter q ter um certo investimento), ou usar algo como o Google Play Services (https://developers.google.com/games/services/), ou o Game Center da Apple (https://developer.apple.com/game-center/), na Asset Store da Unity já têm vários pacotes prontos pra usar.

Answer (score 0):

Use o playerprefs

Para armazenar:

if (score > highScore) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(highScoreKey, score);
 }

para buscar:

highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(highScoreKey, 0);